# Docker Engine fails on Azure Batch node

Tags: azure, docker, azure-batch, docker-engine

### Scenario

I create a pool with multiple nodes (base image is Ubuntu Server 16.04), and provide the following start up command:
`/bin/bash -c 'set -o pipefail; export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive ; sudo -E apt update ; sudo -E apt upgrade -y ; sudo -E apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-transport-https curl software-properties-common ; curl -fsSL "https://sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xee6d536cf7dc86e2d7d56f59a178ac6c6238f52e" | sudo -E apt-key add - ; sudo -E apt-add-repository "deb https://packages.docker.com/1.13/apt/repo/ ubuntu-$(lsb_release -cs) main" ; sudo -E apt-get update ; sudo -E apt-get install -y docker-engine ; sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER ; sudo -E service docker start ; journalctl -xe; wait'`

The command servers the only purpose to install Docker Engine. Note also that I removed the option `set -e` in order to be able to run the command `journalctl -xe` and catch the following error.

### Error

When creating the aforementioned pool, some nodes will fail the starting task. The behavior appears to be random, as not always a node fails, and, as mentioned, the other nodes do not fail.
The behavior does not depend on the size of the node (I tried both D2_v3 and NC6).

This is the output of `journalctl -xe`:

```
Oct 12 09:19:40 7d8bb094c57c400582f6031d59f1630000000A systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.socket has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Oct 12 09:19:40 7d8bb094c57c400582f6031d59f1630000000A systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has begun starting up.
Oct 12 09:19:40 7d8bb094c57c400582f6031d59f1630000000A dockerd[24473]: time="2017-10-12T09:19:40.605332263Z" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 24492"
Oct 12 09:19:41 7d8bb094c57c400582f6031d59f1630000000A dockerd[24473]: time="2017-10-12T09:19:41.608293321Z" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: aufs"
Oct 12 09:19:41 7d8bb094c57c400582f6031d59f1630000000A dockerd[24473]: time="2017-10-12T09:19:41.626089049Z" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
Oct 12 09:19:41 7d8bb094c57c400582f6031d59f1630000000A dockerd[24473]: time="2017-10-12T09:19:41.626378756Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit"
Oct 12 09:19:41 7d8bb094c57c400582f6031d59f1630000000A dockerd[24473]: time="2017-10-12T09:19:41.626558660Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Oct 12 09:19:41 7d8bb094c57c400582f6031d59f1630000000A dockerd[24473]: time="2017-10-12T09:19:41.626698864Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Oct 12 09:19:41 7d8bb094c57c400582f6031d59f1630000000A dockerd[24473]: time="2017-10-12T09:19:41.626834867Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight"
Oct 12 09:19:41 7d8bb094c57c400582f6031d59f1630000000A dockerd[24473]: time="2017-10-12T09:19:41.626970070Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight_device"
Oct 12 09:19:41 7d8bb094c57c400582f6031d59f1630000000A dockerd[24473]: time="2017-10-12T09:19:41.627384080Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Oct 12 09:19:41 7d8bb094c57c400582f6031d59f1630000000A dockerd[24473]: time="2017-10-12T09:19:41.630900065Z" level=info msg="Firewalld running: false"
Oct 12 09:19:41 7d8bb094c57c400582f6031d59f1630000000A dockerd[24473]: time="2017-10-12T09:19:41.661877309Z" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Oct 12 09:19:41 7d8bb094c57c400582f6031d59f1630000000A kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): docker0: link is not ready
Oct 12 09:19:41 7d8bb094c57c400582f6031d59f1630000000A dockerd[24473]: time="2017-10-12T09:19:41.996853856Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Oct 12 09:19:42 7d8bb094c57c400582f6031d59f1630000000A kernel: aufs au_opts_verify:1585:dockerd[24490]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Oct 12 09:19:45 7d8bb094c57c400582f6031d59f1630000000A systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Oct 12 09:19:45 7d8bb094c57c400582f6031d59f1630000000A systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Oct 12 09:19:45 7d8bb094c57c400582f6031d59f1630000000A systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 12 09:19:45 7d8bb094c57c400582f6031d59f1630000000A systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

It appears that something went wrong in the creation of the network interface, but I'm not sure what and, especially, how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer, 2017-10-18:**

The issue has been fixed with the `latest` platform image of Canonical UbuntuServer 16.04-LTS, and works with Go/Docker again.

**Original Answer:**

There's nothing wrong with your code. There's an [issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-azure/+bug/1719045) with the Canonical UbuntuServer 16.04-LTS `201709190` platform image (which is, at this time, also `latest`) and Go/Docker.

Set the version of the image to deploy to `201708151` temporarily while the issue is fixed.

As an aside: if you're using Docker and Azure Batch, you should take a look at [Batch Shipyard](https://github.com/Azure/batch-shipyard) which provides this functionality. (full disclosure: I'm a contributor for this code.)